# How to find the strings DO NOT starts with "2012" using regular expressions?

Tags: regex, r

Hi I have some date format strings, and I want to find out those ones which do not start with "**2012**" using regular expression (in R). I have tried `grep("^[^2012]",dataset)` but it did not work. And I have also tried `grep("^[^2][^0][^1][^2]",dataset)` and still it did not work. What is the *pattern* for this question? Your help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `!` in front of `grepl`:

```
 x[ !grepl("^2012", x) ]
```

`grep("^[^2012] , ...)` would reject any values that started with any of those digits. (I'm not sure why the second one didn't work.) Gustav's suggestion only works if you specify perl=TRUE:

```
x[ grep("^(?!2012)", x, perl=TRUE) ]
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tested both of the two methods and it worked fine!

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is supported in R's regex, but in general you can do:

```
"^(?!2012)"
```

Answer (score 3):

`grep` has an `invert=TRUE` option too:

```
x <- c("2012out", "2include")
grep("^2012",x,invert=TRUE)
#[1] 2

grep("^2012",x,invert=TRUE,value=TRUE)
#[1] "2include"
```